# ngnix php curl old SSL session ID is stale, removing

Tags: nginx, ssl, curl, session, mod-ssl

I am making a php curl request from nginx server to apache server

It shows `old SSL session ID is stale, removing`

As per the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18448337/8280010) I have changed the SSLSessionCacheTimeout in bitnami apache server but still the error occurs. I have changed SSLSessionCacheTimeout to 1500.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

NOTE: When I run the same api in restclient it works. but when I am calling from the nginx server it is error.

Comment: My guess it is some recent curl bug in 7.80 or even in 7.76 as well   , maybe you can try the same with older curl version(s) and confirm my guess.

Comment: @noonex Hi, cURL version 7.64.0 in nginx server.

Comment: @noonex Sorry, Its my blunter mistake, there is a space in the url when I am calling from the code. so the error occurs. But when I tested in restclient it accepts the space.